# R - Formatting of text for subsetting from a list by name

Tags: r

I have a data frame, "Customers_list", as follows:

```
Customer_No    Entry_Time   Exit_Time(Adjusted)
   123             1            2
   295             3            5
   337             5            4
```

and another list of matrices (named "Customers_details"), where each matrix correspond to each unique customer number. The individual matrices have time as rows, and customers' details as columns.

I would like to subset the customers from the list of matrices, based on Exit_Time(Adjusted) >= Entry_Time.

I have tried:

```
Customers_details[noquote(paste("c(", paste(sprintf("'%d'",subset(Customers_list[,"Customer_No"],"Exit_Time(Adjusted)" >= "Entry_Time"),collapse=","), ")", sep=""))]
```

But it does not seem to work, even though the printed output of the paste function gives me:

```
c('123','295')
```

Whereas if I had typed the code Customers_details[c('123','295')] directly, I would have managed to subset the 2 relevant matrices.

Comment: why not just `Customers_details[Customers_details$Exit_Time(Adjusted) >= Customers_details$Entry_Time, "Customer_No"]`

Comment: Did you mean "Customers_list" instead of "Customers_details"? 

The issue is that my subsetting criteria is based on Customers_lists, and that I need this information to retrieve the appropriate matrices from the array "Customers_details". The customers' numbers are not necessarily in order, hence I need to refer to them by name and not indexing

Comment: Yes, I mean Customers_list

Comment: That gives me the result 123 295. But what I require to subset these relevant matrices from the list of matrices is Customers_details[c('123','295')] instead.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear earlier. My Customers_details is essentially a list of many matrices, where each matrix correspond to one particular customer. I tried, but couldn't subset the list in the manner you mentioned above.

Comment: can you please show your sample of the data for `Customer_details`, if its a list and contain matrices, then you may try this `Customer_details[names(Customer_details) %in% sapply(labelsx, as.character)]` where labelsx is defined as below `labelsx <- Customers_list[Customers_list$Exit_Time > Customers_list$Entry_Time,"Customer_No"]` , This will work only if the names of list has customer_no values

Comment: Please use `dput` to share data for `Customer_details`